# serialize() and unserialize() confusion and escaping

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, escaping

I have some problem regarding `serialize()` and `unserialize()`  .

I am writing a function for Wordpress, the function is actually a settings page and I am trying to export and import the array of the settings using two input fields.

The code (and page)  is a bit long , so I post it [HERE ON PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/DNh7bG5p) , which is a bit more comfortable .

The problem that I have though, is that wordpress saves the options (or settings ) using the settings API as a serialized array.

The function I have can successful show the options like :

```
a:10:{s:24:"brsa_copyright_meta_text";s:0:"";s:25:"brsa_remove_menu_css_list";s:0:"";s:19:"brsa_remove_submenu";s:0:"";s:21:"brsa_remove_menu_list";s:0:"";s:15:"brsa_footer_txt";s:0:"";s:22:"brsa_dash_wdgt_content";s:0:"";s:36:"brsa_add_custom_login_message_string";s:0:"";s:21:"brsa_login_url_string";s:0:"";s:21:"brsa_login_alt_string";s:0:"";s:14:"brsa_login_img";s:0:"";}
```

which is ok . it is serialized , but when I try to insert it to the DB (or show it on the other field by pressing the import button) it actually being `escaped` i think, and in any way , it does not insert to the DB as serialized , but as a string ..

```
a:10:{s:24:\"brsa_copyright_meta_text\";s:0:\"\";s:25:\"brsa_remove_menu_css_list\";s:0:\"\";s:19:\"brsa_remove_submenu\";s:0:\"\";s:21:\"brsa_remove_menu_list\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"brsa_footer_txt\";s:0:\"\";s:22:\"brsa_dash_wdgt_content\";s:0:\"\";s:36:\"brsa_add_custom_login_message_string\";s:0:\"\";s:21:\"brsa_login_url_string\";s:0:\"\";s:21:\"brsa_login_alt_string\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"brsa_login_img\";s:0:\"\";}
```

..Making the whole code unusable.
The relative part of the code is this :

```
 $my_options = get_option( 'o99_brsa_settings' );


    $currentsettings = "";
        if ( isset( $_POST['import'] ) && trim($_POST['exccc']) != "" ) {
            $currentsettings = $_POST['exccc'];
            update_option( 'o99_brsa_settings', serialize($currentsettings));

        } elseif ( isset( $my_options ) && ( $my_options != "" ) ) {
            if ($o99_brsa_options['brsa_keep_settings_exp'] !='') {
            $currentsettings = $o99_brsa_options['brsa_keep_settings_exp'];  
            } else {
                $currentsettings =  serialize( $my_options );
            }
        }
```

Although I do believe that the [-- whole code --](http://pastebin.com/DNh7bG5p) should be seen in order to understand how it should work..

Except for the fac that it does not work, I am not quite sure in anything as to what is the problem, but first I would like to know *why is the value being `/escaped/`* and how to prevent it ?

Any other help would also be greatly appreciated ..

Comment: Your server might have `magic_quotes` enabled. Ask your administrator to disabled it. If you need `magic_quotes` you _are doing it wrong_, a workaround for this scenario would be to `stripslashes` your input which undoes the `magic_quotes` transformation.

Comment: Show us the implementation of `update_option` then, you've probably got an escape too many.

Comment: @Frits van Campen -  but wont `stripslashes` can also harm inside information that might have slashes ??

Comment: not if `magic_quotes` is turned on. That's the whole point. Of course, randomly calling `stripslashes` on input will break your input. Make sure what you're dealing with first.

Comment: @Frits van Campen - `update_option` is a wordpress core function..I am quite sure that it works ok (at least it does for some millions of users :-) - even if not for me.. )

Comment: @Frits van Campen +1 for the  `magic quotes`. my colleague has enabled it . and indeed `stripslashes` works. the function still fails on all levels, but at least that particular problem is solved . Thnaks (you can add it as an answer for me to accept ..)

Comment: Ha, I knew it! :D Ask your colleague to bring in pie for the whole office as punishment.

Comment: @Frits van Campen - thanks again :-) as for the pie, there is as much little chance for that as for me to make this function work :-) it still does not insert as serialized data , and I was wondering , can it be an RTL / LTR problem ?? can that actually make the data to not be recognized as the right format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server might have `magic_quotes` enabled. Ask your administrator to disabled it.

Comment: Now , following this - Is there a way to check if `magic_quotes` are enables on run-time ?